# Centre view in parent and below a certain view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

1. `View` A is to be centered in the Parent
2. `View` B (`TextView`) is to appear at the top of the Parent.
3. But as view B increases in height and reaches View A, then it should push down View A as much as required to show all its content.

If i use a relative layout, I can either alight View A to center vertical of the Parent OR below View B. But I can't achieve both. 
Also, #3 seems to be possible only if View A is below View B in the Relative Layout but then I can't make it center in parent to begin with, while View B height is not long enough to reach View A.

Could someone provide some suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Its good if your share any image or screenshot of your required output

Comment: Use ConstraintLayout and set constraints. It's better version of PercentRelativeLayout which let's you use percentages and set views relative to each other without nesting them.

Comment: @Thracian: Could you explain how?

Comment: @Sunny ConstraintLayout is very easy to learn. Follow this tutorial and you will master it 15 minutes. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0

To set constraints dynamically search SO, i haven't changed anything on runtime yet. It also makes easier to use location base animations for views. Quite easy to move view from one place to another too with 2 layouts.

Comment: You don't need parents with ConstraintLayout, everything can be position on any part of the screen or relative to other views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="TextView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="TextView2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Set minHeight for the first View as programmatically.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int height = linearLayout.getHeight(); // set height/2 as minHeight for the first view
            linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
```

Gives this result :

[image]

Hope this will help you :)